# Disqus for Android

Tags: android, disqus

Searching Disqus' website, I am surprised that there is no clear indication that any API exists for integrating their discussion into an Android app. Is that true or has anyone ever integrated Disqus into their Android app?

Comment: Our company website integrated it. After I used the id and short name they provided, I was able to load the disqus in Android. I am also looking for integrating from app with the keys provided by Disqus

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog on the issue here

http://globeotter.com/blog/disqus-android-code/

You can do this by using a webview and a few tricks.